# Serialization exception in java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a legacy code that I have been getting headache working on.
So here we go.

```
public class SelectionItem implements Serializable {
private String            id;
private String            description;

public SelectionItem(String id, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
public class AC2GuiNamedConfigurationBean implements Serializable {
private static final long             serialVersionUID =    -6964702304270690484L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int                           id;

@Column(length = 32768)
private HashMap<String, Serializable> configurationData;

...
```

The configurationData is merely made up of SelectionItem objects.
So whenever I try to update my bean, I get

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

which is caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SelectionItem from [Module "org.hibernate:main"...
```

what I really don't understand because the SelectionItem class is present.
I can save the bean as many times as I want without error as long as there is no change in the configurationData field. But any changes, as little they might be, will throw the exception.

Thanks

Comment: did you try cleaning your project and rebuilding?

Comment: Are there already SelectionItems stored within the database?

Comment: "Because the SelectionItem class is present". Well, no, it isn't. Not on the classpath. The exception says so. And why isn't it in a package?

Comment: Hi @suenda. I do it all the times. I'm working on a feature branch and I run mvn clean install before I do test the code

Comment: you should use the Map interface instead of HashMap directly

Comment: What about loading... is deserialization working correctly? What data-type are your columns of?

Comment: Hi @EJP. Great point. The application is a multi modules project and the SelectionItem goes in a module other than the module where I save the bean. Thank you for the hint. How I haven't thought about that one before?

Comment: Well, the hint didn't work out. The class is really there. And as I have written above, I can save a new bean without problem. The problem occurs only when the configurationData field contains changes.